# Possible to run React JS and Wordpress on the same web server?

Tags: wordpress, apache, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the Wordpress REST API to provide a back end to my React JS front end. Right now both are running on separate Apache servers on AWS and all works well.

Is it possible to run both on the same server? So that my React front end is making requests to Wordpress on the same server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, if you want to use Apache to handle distributing your frontend and handling the WP backend, read up on Virtual Hosts: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

The gist of it is that you'll have a VH for your frontend

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com <-- see here
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/client
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and a VH for your backend

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias api.example.com <-- and here
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/server
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense. Is it possible to test this without having to purchase and setup a domain name, using the IP or current DNS of the AWS instance instead for example? Or would that involve a different setup, e.g. Aliases

Comment: To test it without a domain, use different ports and the instance IP.